Scripting: custom export file
I use the Defold game engine, its very new and very barebones, but i got used to it very fast and decided to both use it in future projects - specially now that im switching to 3D - and to contribute to it. The main problem for Defold right now is the lack of a proper scene/level editor and thats where Blender comes in. My original idea was to use Blender as a scene/level editor and export very basic data such as transformations and basic custom properties. My first thought was to just export a GLTF file and use the nodes and the custom properties to mount a scene in Defold. Thing is, the exported GLTF is quite complicated and hard to navigate and use. Take this scene for example:

Its just Suzanne in an empty scene, following the export configurations I expected the final result to be very simple (just like the scene itself). But it turned out to not be really like this:

I tried exporting without meshes, materials, vertex colors... Still, the GLTF scene was delivered in a very odd manner:
{
"asset":{
    "generator":"Khronos glTF Blender I/O v4.3.47",
    "version":"2.0"
},
"scene":0,
"scenes":[
    {
        "name":"Scene",
        "nodes":[
            0
        ]
    }
],
"nodes":[
    {
        "extras":{
            "random_data":1.0,
            "is_this_checked":true
        },
        "mesh":0,
        "name":"Monkey",
        "translation":[
            -6.501957893371582,
            2.798858880996704,
            -2.6240763664245605
        ]
    }
],
"meshes":[
    {
        "name":"Suzanne",
        "primitives":[
            {
                "attributes":{
                    "POSITION":0
                },
                "indices":1
            }
        ]
    }
],
"accessors":[
    {
        "bufferView":0,
        "componentType":5126,
        "count":2532,
        "max":[
            1.325934886932373,
            0.9392361640930176,
            0.8223199844360352
        ],
        "min":[
            -1.325934886932373,
            -0.9704862236976624,
            -0.7782661318778992
        ],
        "type":"VEC3"
    },
    {
        "bufferView":1,
        "componentType":5123,
        "count":11838,
        "type":"SCALAR"
    }
],
"bufferViews":[
    {
        "buffer":0,
        "byteLength":30384,
        "byteOffset":0,
        "target":34962
    },
    {
        "buffer":0,
        "byteLength":23676,
        "byteOffset":30384,
        "target":34963
    }
],
"buffers":[
    {
        "byteLength":54060,
        "uri":"test_map.bin"
    }
]

}
The nodes part is the actuall data im interested in, but alongside it comes a lot of "garbage"/unwanted info as well, besides it coming weirdly formated - I mean, why is it "extras" isntead of just "Custom Properties" or something like this? I first thought that i'd have to create my own custom export script for this, which I think should be the way to go, since I will eventually need more functionalities, in specific, im also planning to export curves to create paths and alike. Although i found many resources on Blender Python scripting, I did not find many on export specifically, most were about automating very simple tasks like creating a button to add a prefab mesh or cube. To be direct here, im asking for some guidance on what and where should I search for to accomplish my objectives - manipulate the export routine to filter what gets, doesnt get or how it gets into exported into a file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The GLTF importer/exporter is written and managed by the KhronosGroup on Github here so you should ask any questions about it there.

@JohnEason my question is not about GLTF specificaly, im more interested in how i can customize the export, i thought i made that clear at the end. The GLTF example i gave is just because its the only thing that more closely resambles a scene that blender can export to. Sorry for any confusion. I also cant reply to your comment specifically, hence im tagging you.

The complete source to the exporter is on that Github page and a question like that is really not suitable for this Q&A site which is here to help with problems using Blender, not to customise exporters..

Guess a question about blender python API then really isnt blender related at all. But thanks for the call out, off course ill read a whole github to understand it all, much thanks!

There are no Blender developers here and no-one here works for or has any association with the Blender Foundation so you'd be better asking the developers of the exporter directly. Sorry we can't help further.

This site is not to teach you the basics of how to write a Python add on, but how to fix an addon writing problem you’re stuck on. You asked for resources on how to export, and we told you the best we could. The back-and-forth of developing the modified exporter in the way you want would be far too long for a single question post on this site. If you don’t want a full add-on but just need a Jerry rig script to get you by, be aware that Python can save files directly without Blender, via the open() function. I also suggest you look into fully parsing the gLTF, but IDK ‍♂️. Merry Christmas!
